# TypeError: Cannot read property 'loadAsync' of null

Tags: react-native, fonts, expo

I want import custom fonts in react native (expo) project

I installed `expo-font` and `expo-file-system` and i wrote some codes for load and use fonts

there is my code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button} from 'react-native-paper';
import { AppLoading, Font } from 'expo';

export class ButtonSample extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state={
            fontLoaded:false
        }
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        try {
          await Font.loadAsync({
            'Ranchers': require('../assets/fonts/Ranchers-Regular.ttf'),
            'Inter-SemiBoldItalic': 'https://rsms.me/inter/font-files/Inter-SemiBoldItalic.otf?v=3.12',
          });

          this.setState({ fontLoaded: true });
          alert('fonts are loaded');
        } catch (error) {
          alert(error);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                {this.state.fontLoaded ? ( 
                        <Button style={{marginTop:20, fontFamily: "Ranchers"}} icon="box" mode="contained" onPress={() => alert('Pressed')}>
                            Click me
                        </Button>
                ) : (
                     <AppLoading />
                )}
                
            </>

        );
    }
}
```

What's problem? is there possible expo-font installation have any problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are importing Font from "expo" (think that is deprecated) and not from "expo-font".

Just do:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button} from 'react-native-paper';
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
import * as Font from "expo-font"; // <---

export class ButtonSample extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state={
            fontLoaded:false
        }
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        try {
          await Font.loadAsync({
            'Ranchers': require('../assets/fonts/Ranchers-Regular.ttf'),
            'Inter-SemiBoldItalic': 'https://rsms.me/inter/font-files/Inter-SemiBoldItalic.otf?v=3.12',
          });

          this.setState({ fontLoaded: true });
          alert('fonts are loaded');
        } catch (error) {
          alert(error);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                {this.state.fontLoaded ? ( 
                        <Button style={{marginTop:20, fontFamily: "Ranchers"}} icon="box" mode="contained" onPress={() => alert('Pressed')}>
                            Click me
                        </Button>
                ) : (
                     <AppLoading />
                )}
                
            </>

        );
    }
}
```

And will work fine. Also I recommend you to code your own Splash Screen to do this stuff.

Comment: Oh, Thank you so much :)